# The Structure of a Service Class in Android - Questions and Check Work

Tags: android, android-service, android-timer

I am currently resuming a project I had been working on, and starting from scratch to recreate it.
However, upon creating a Service class, I noticed something - in my old project, a method inside the Service called onStartCommand contains all of the code that needs to be fired, whereas in my new project when I create a Service class, this method is nowhere to be found.

- Do I need to manually ADD this "onStartCommand" method to contain my service code?

- If not, where exactly would my code go? It seems in my "old" project's code, I completely comment-block public TimerService, and pass null into IBinder, and create onStartCommand etc instead.. and I can't quite figure out why.

- While i'm here, can someone please double-check my CountdownTimer code below? and if it's correct, should I be putting it inside of a Thread?
When I create a new Service Class, it looks like this:

```
public class TimerService extends Service {

    public TimerService() {

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");

    }

}
```

However in my old Project, my Service class looks like this:

```
public class TimerService extends Service {

/*
public TimerService() {

}
*/

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    intent.getStringExtra("TIMER_VALUE");

    String string_timerValue;
    string_timerValue = intent.getStringExtra("TIMER_VALUE");

    long long_timerValue;
    long_timerValue = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(string_timerValue));

    // I DO NOT WANT ANY TICK VALUE, SO GIVE IT FULL TIMER VALUE
    long long_tickValue;
    long_tickValue = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(string_timerValue));

    new CountDownTimer(long_timerValue, long_tickValue) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // DO NOTHING
        }

        public void onFinish() {

            Toast.makeText(TimerService.this, "TIMES UP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            stopService(intent);

        }
    }.start();

    return START_STICKY;

    // END OF onStartCommand
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

// END OF ENTIRE SERVICE CLASS
}
```

THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to manually ADD this "onStartCommand" method to contain my service code?

Yes.

> can someone please double-check my CountdownTimer code below?

Only create a service when one is absolutely necessary. It is unclear why this service is necessary.

Beyond that:

- Use `stopSelf()`, not `stopService()`, to stop a service from inside that service.
- Examining `Intent` extras *and* using `START_STICKY` is not a good combination. `START_STICKY` says "if you terminate my process to free up system RAM, please restart my service when possible, but pass `null` for the `Intent`". That will cause your service to crash with a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.. Well my objective is to have a broadcast listener, which when fired, brings up a dialog box activity, which the user enters a value into a edittext and presses OK.. The activity then disappears, and runs the timer in the background, and when the time expires, a new activity opens/code fires.. I assumed a Service would be needed to do the Timer in the background. If not, how else would I go about it, as not to get killed by the system while it's in the background? Isn't background processes what a Service is used for? Also, if not START_STICKY, then what Flag to use?

Comment: @Studio2bDesigns: "how else would I go about it" -- `AlarmManager`, most likely. "as not to get killed by the system while it's in the background?" -- you *want* to be "killed by the system". **Only have a service running when it is actively delivering value to the user**. Sitting around watching the clock tick is not actively delivering value to the user.

Comment: So just to clarify, you're suggesting **instead** of closing the Activity and starting a Service to run the AlarmManager, I should simply put the AlarmManager code within the actual **Activity**, directly prior to closing the Activity? I wasn't sure if the AlarmManager would remain in action if I were to close the Activity, that's why I was starting a Service to do it in the background. **Are you saying the Activity can be closed while still running the AlarmManager code in the background?** Also, for future reference, what FLAG **would I have** used instead of START_STICKY?

Comment: @Studio2bDesigns: "I wasn't sure if the AlarmManager would remain in action if I were to close the Activity" -- the point of `AlarmManager` is to give your app control at a requested time, whether you have a running process right then or not. Note that the time is not necessarily precise, given limits imposed by Doze mode and app standby on Android 6.0+ devices. "Also, for future reference, what FLAG would I have used instead of START_STICKY?" -- it's not that simple. The closest simple thing is to get rid of the `Intent` extras, in which case `START_STICKY` is user-hostile but would work.

Comment: You said the AlarmManager isn't precise - but I need it to fire my code after the exact amount of Minutes the user had entered into an EditText.. So is AlarmManager not the best solution then?

Comment: @Studio2bDesigns: Basically, what you want isn't something that Android offers very well, due to power concerns. If the duration of the delay is under an hour, then `AlarmManager` should be OK. The only thing that is fairly precise for longer delays is `setAlarmClock()` on `AlarmManager`, and that is supposed to be used by alarm clock apps -- I do not know if users will consider your app to be one or not.

Comment: Thank you so much for the kind and helpful words of advice. My last question would be, should I surround the AlarmManager code within a Thread? Also I posted a separate question this morning, but no replies yet, if you're feeling extra helpful ;)

Comment: @Studio2bDesigns: "should I surround the AlarmManager code within a Thread?" -- I do not know what "the AlarmManager code" is. If you mean calling APIs on `AlarmManager`, that does not need to be done on a background thread. If you mean the work that is triggered by `AlarmManager`... if it involves any sort of I/O (disk, database, network) or a lot of calculations, then yes. That is not unique to `AlarmManager`, though.